# Problems with filepath: the file exists, but java throws an exce

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I know for a fact that the given file exists in this directory. .class file is in the same directory. What's wrong with the path?

```
   String fileName = "/home/security/workspace/SecondProject/src/config.txt";
   File file = new File(fileName);
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
   InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, charset);
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
   String line;
   while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
      //process the line
      System.out.println(line);
   }
   br.close();
```

The error is as follows:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/security/workspace/SecondProject/src/config.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:92)
```

Should it be an absolute path? /config.txt doesn't seem to work either.

EDIT: 
Here's a proof, I don't know of any better way to prove it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p2MW.jpg

Here's the terminal:
security@security:~/workspace/SecondProject/src$ ls
Config.txt  JDBCExample.class  JDBCExample.java

Comment: _I know for a fact_  Can you show proof?

Comment: I don't believe you. I trust the JDK more than I trust you. Please **prove** that the file exists, and can be read by the current user.

Comment: I edited the original post with the proof

Comment: The file is named `Config.txt`, not `config.txt`. Sigh. Voting to close for "simple typographical error"

Comment: I know for a fact that case-sensitivity exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File names are case sensitive. You need to specify the file with a capital C:

```
 String fileName = "/home/security/workspace/SecondProject/src/Config.txt";
```